# Unable to install weblogic server

Tags: weblogic

Starting check : CheckJDKVersion
Problem: This JDK version was not certified at the time it was made generally available. It may have been certified following general availability.

Recommendation: Check the Supported System Configurations Guide (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html) for further details. Press "Next" if you wish to continue.

Expected result: 1.8.0_191
Actual result: 18
Warning: Check:CheckJDKVersion completed with warnings.

Validations are enabled for this session.
Verifying data
Copying Files
Internal Error: File Copy failed. Aborting Install

The log(s) can be found here: C:\Users\KUNAL\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-04-10_02-04-52PM.

Press Enter to exit

Answer (score 0):

Your WebLogic server version is not supported with Java 18. You must use Oracle JDK 8.